# Check if an array exists in a BsonValue type

Tags: c#

I have a BsonValue `abc` and looking for a way to check if it contains array or not. The structure is as below:

```
"abc":[
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
.
.
"mno":{
"pqr":[
"valuefirst",
"valuesecond"
]
},
.
.
]
```

In C# code when I try to check if array pqr exists like 
`if(abc["mno"]["pqr"] != null)`, I get KeyNotFoundException. It is wrong on my part to index `abc` for `pqr` or `mno` when it doesn't exist. So, how can `abc`  which is stored as a BsonValue be checked for the existence of these and overcome the exception? Thought of using `filter`. But that works for `BsonDocument`(Please correct me if I am wrong). What is the work around for this?

Comment: As far as I know you can't index on a string in `Bson` format, so you deserialize it to a datastructure. Which datastructure are you using?

Comment: Have not used any, yet. If I were to use, shouldn't I be using an array?

Comment: how do you do `if(abc["mno"]["pqr"]` if you haven't deserialized yet? If you'd type `if(abc["mno"]["pqr"])` you'd get all kinds of errors.